# Multiplication in Loops of Unknown Length

Tags: python, loops, multiplication

I've been stuck on this code from mypy2 for the last hour but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. It wants me to write a program that multiplies many numbers together. Where the program will keep asking the user for numbers until they enter 0.

When they enter 0, it exits the loop and doesn't multiply the other numbers by 0. Finally, it prints the final large number with the statement print("The final answer is", number).

"For example, if the user enters 2, 5, 4, then 0, the answer should be 40. You can calculate this by starting at 1, multiplying that by 2 to get 2. Then multiplying that by 5 to get 10. Then multiplying that by 4 to get 40."

It says I need one variable to store the user’s input, and another to keep track of the big multiplied number.

Comment: Please provide the code. And also, multiplying any number with 0 = 0?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
my_number = 1
while True:
    new_number = int(input("Enter any number to multiply:"))
    if new_number == 0:
        print(f"Result is: {my_number}")
        break

    my_number *= new_number
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help :) I'm new at coding and have really only worked with conditionals in my class. I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. I'm not familiar with what True means, break or *=.

Comment: `True` is a [boolean value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type). If the condition is `True`, the while loop will continue forever. `break` tells the control flow to break out of the loop (in this case the `while True:` loop), so it does not actually loop forever. `x *= y` is just shorthand for `x = x * y`.

Comment: @esier0 You mentioned that the code does not work for you. How do you run it? I suggest to save the code i provided into a file.py file and execute it via command line, copy pasting it into the python shell will not work.

Comment: My bad! It works when I actually put it on my Python! I'm just trying to figure out why it doesn't on mypy2 now since that's where I have to put the solution in. Thank u again

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet for you

```
product=1
while(True):
    num=int(input())
    if(num==0):
        print("Value: ",product)
       break
product*=num
```